# Accessing elements in array of pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to execute following C program using gcc compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int *a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    printf("\narr0=%d\n", *a);
    printf("arr1=%d\n", *(a+1));
    printf("arr2=%d\n", *a+2);
    printf("arr3=%d\n", *a+3);
    printf("arr4=%d\n", *a+4);

    return 0;
}

Output:-
arr0=1
arr1=2
arr2=9
arr3=13
arr4=17
```

I am not able to understand what is happening when I skip parenthesis for *a+2, *a+3, *a+4.
For *a+2 it manipulates as :

```
= *a+2
= *a+(4*2)           4 ->Size of int
= 1+(8)
So, *a+2 = 9
```

Same way it does for others.

But I am expecting output as following. (?)

```
arr0=1
arr1=2
arr2=3
arr3=4
arr4=5
```

I know, the way I have declared array of pointers in not good way to do it.

Can anyone explain what is happening here ?

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings.  If your compiler didn't give you warnings about the array initializers not being pointers, either turn on the warnings, or get yourself a better compiler (and turn on the warnings it provides).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring a bunch of pointers to invalid addresses, since the small integers are very typically *not* valid integer pointers. You should be getting compiler warnings for this by the way; it's a good idea to *read* those and fix them before posting a question here. Or at least mention that you do get warnings.

As soon as you dereference any of these, undefined behavior strikes.

It's good that you never do, all you do is index into the array itself, and print the pointers using the wrong format specifier (you should use `%p`, not `%d`).

Comment: Although it is showing undefined behavior there is some pattern in the output, if I continue printing, this pattern continues. And this pattern appears for short int, char also.

Answer (score 4):

Unary `*` has higher precedence than binary `+`, so `*(a + i)` and `*a + i` are interpreted differently.

`*(a + i)` is equivalent to `a[i]`; you're retrieving the `i`'th *element* of `a`, so `*(a + 2)` would be the same as `a[2]` which would be `3`.

`*a + i` is equivalent to `a[0] + i`; since `a[0]` is type `int *`, the result of `a[0] + i` is the value of the *`i`'th pointer to `int`* after `a[0]`.  If `sizeof (int *)` is 4 and `a[0]` equals `1`, then `*a + 1` will be `5`, `*a + 2` will be `9`, etc.

Use the `%p` conversion specifier to print pointer values:

```
printf("*a + 2 = %p\n", *a + 2);
```

If you want to index into an array, use subscript notation (`a[i]`).  Using pointer notation is confusing and error-prone (as you have discovered).

Comment: When I do it for chat, short int, double it shows me same pattern. For int* it adds 4, for char* - it adds 4, for short int* - it adds , for double* - it adds 7. sizeof (int *), sizeof (char*), sizeof (short int *), sizeof (double *) is 4. If it is adding size of pointer then It should add 4 for every data type. But this is not happening.